# Identity Framework Web API(.Net 8) how to control the Token Expire time

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have been using **Identity Framework packages** in my ASP.Net Core Web API Project(.Net8). I have the following setup:

On the Program.cs:

```
//The AddIdentityApiEndpoints add the authentication itself so i don't need to declare it. The problem is I don't have any way to control the Token

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GeneralAccess", policy =>
           policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.IsInRole("Admin") ||
            context.User.IsInRole("User")));
}); 

//Setup Database Context
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DemoSecurityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecurityConnection")));


//This will add the API endpoints for the Identity DB
builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<DemoUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    //.AddIdentity<DemoUser, DemoIdentityRoles>()
    .AddRoles<DemoIdentityRoles>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DemoSecurityDbContext>();

app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi<DemoUser>();
```

I have been digging around the **MapIdentityApi** and the SignManager to understand how can I change the Token expiry date, at the moment is set to 3600 but I can't find an easy way to overwrite this value.
I can't see where the token is generated in the code and 3600 is too much
{
"tokenType": "Bearer",
"accessToken": "*",
"expiresIn": **3600**,
"refreshToken": "*"
}

I have been looking across all the visible code.
I have been searching on the web but no one has raised this question.
Ideally I would like a simple answer where I can use the built in code from the Indentity Framework API ./Account/Login endpoint.

Here is the code from from the AddIdentityApiEndpoints it doesn't look I have any control on the token

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentityApiEndpoints<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> configure)
        where TUser : class, new()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(services);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(configure);

        services
            .AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.BearerAndApplicationScheme)
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, CompositeIdentityHandler>(IdentityConstants.BearerAndApplicationScheme, null, compositeOptions =>
            {
                compositeOptions.ForwardDefault = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
                compositeOptions.ForwardAuthenticate = IdentityConstants.BearerAndApplicationScheme;
            })
            .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme)
            .AddIdentityCookies();

        return services.AddIdentityCore<TUser>(configure)
            .AddApiEndpoints();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the token expiry duration in ASP.NET Core Identity JWT tokens, you can modify the TokenValidationParameters when configuring JWT authentication. In your Program.cs, where you configure authentication using JWT bearer, you can adjust the TokenValidationParameters as follows:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero, // Remove the clock skew
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
    };
});
```

setting ClockSkew to TimeSpan.Zero, you effectively disable the clock skew, meaning the token will expire strictly according to the exp claim value in the token payload.
Now, to set the token expiration time explicitly, you can do it while generating the token. If you're using SignInManager to generate tokens, you can specify the expiration time there. Here's how you can do it:

```
var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (signInResult.Succeeded)
{
    // Generate token
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            // Add other claims as needed
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60), // Set the expiration time here
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return Ok(new
    {
        tokenType = "Bearer",
        accessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
        expiresIn = 3600, // This value will be overwritten by the expiration time set in tokenDescriptor
        refreshToken = ""
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using the app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi<DemoUser>(); and I'm using the /login endpoint, so I don't have control on how the token generation. I don't want to create my own login method. I'm trying to use the framework API as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme,
o =>
{
    o.BearerTokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
}
```

Comment: I get the error Schema already exists, the MapApiEndpoint already add the schema

Comment: If possible can you please share your code via github?

Comment: I'm using at the moment all .net template Web API ASP.NET with Identity Framework package. I'm trying to see how can i control the Identity framework and see how much I might need to overwrite. The problem is if I add your line in the program.cs it complain because IF already declare the scheme and I can't see a way to pass options to IF

Comment: This needs to be added to a place where you are defining your scheme.

Comment: The scheme is defined inside the identity framework so I can't change it unless I wrote my own call